# Доступ к docker registry из контейнера локальной сети

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Здравствуйте.

Возникла необходимость в использовании приватного хранилища для докер-контейнеров, а так же CI посредством Jenkins, который так же под докером. Последний будет билдить контейнеры и отправлять их в приватное хранилище.

Есть определенные трудности, одна из которых: невозможность обращения по хосту в процессе аутентификации докера в приватное хранилище (**docker login registry**). Конфигурация docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:

  registry:
    image: registry:2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./registry:/var/lib/registry
      - ./auth:/auth
      - ./certs:/certs
    environment:
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/domain.crt
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/domain.key

  jenkins:
    build:
      dockerfile: DockerfileJenkins
      context: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7654:8080
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    links:
      - registry:registry
```

В DockerfileJenkins доставляется sudo libltdl-dev (не думаю, что это важно в моих вопросах).

При попытке выполнить комманду **docker login registry** из под jenkins'а получаем сообщение:

> Username: testuser 
>   Password: 
>   Error response from daemon: Get https://registry/v1/users/: dial tcp: lookup registry on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host

Но **ping registry** дает такой результат:

> PING registry (172.19.0.2): 56 data bytes 
>   64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms

Объясните, пожалуйста: почему не работает обращение по хосту?

Вторая из проблем: сертификаты для registry самоподписанные, а соответственно, при работе с хранилищем докер выдает следующую ошибку (при обращении по ip:port):

> Error response from daemon: Get https://172.19.0.2:5000/v1/users/: x509: cannot validate certificate for 172.19.0.2 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

На форумах нашел решение в виде запуска демона докера с ключем **--insecure-registry [domain]**. Но т.к. докер пробрасывается из хост системы - не хотелось бы менять настройки хоста: возможно есть более "красивое" решение задачи? Кроме того, у нас domain - динамический ip из внутренней сети докера, а следовательно придется выставлять статичсский ip для registry, что не "тру вэй" :)

Если в целом опишите как поднять то, что я хочу (или ссылку на статью, можно англ.) - буду очень признателен.

Спасибо за уделенное время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем-то проблема была "решена" обходным путем: пробросом соккета докера хост-машины и привязкой внешнего порта jenkins'а к локалке (127.0.0.1:7654:5000). Работаем с jenkins'ом по ssh туннелю.

Т.к. работаем с соккетом хост машины, пулить и пушим контейнеры не имеет смысла и соответственно проблема коннекта по алиасу отпала.

Если Вы знаете более правильную реализацию такого велосипеда - прошу отписать сюда, буду очень благодарен!

P.S. Хочу заметить, что если Вы городите подобное, нельзя открывать контейнер с хостовым соккетом в мир, т.к. если его ломанут (в моем случае jenkins), то получат доступ ко всем работающим контейнерам, а так же к проброшенным папкам (ключ -v).